# How to delete a property/value from an entity using google cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am learning `google.cloud.datastore`, and like to know how to delete a property along with its value from an `entity`. Also, is it possible to delete a specific or a list of properties from all entities of a certain `kind`?

My understanding is `datastore` stores/manipulates data in a row-wise way (`entities`)?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, all datastore write operations happen, indeed, at the entity level. So in order to modify one or a subset of properties you'd retrieve the entity, modify the property (or delete it, if you want to delete the property) set and save the entity.

The exact details depend on the language and library used. From [Updating an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity):

> To `update` an existing entity, modify the properties of the entity
>   and store it using the key:
>
> PYTHON
>
> ```
> with client.transaction():
>     key = client.key('Task', 'sample_task')
>     task = client.get(key)
>
>     task['done'] = True
>
>     client.put(task)
> ```
>
> The object data overwrites the existing entity. The entire object is
>   sent to Cloud Datastore. If the entity does not exist, the update will
>   fail. If you want to update-or-create an entity, use `upsert` as
>   described previously.
>
> **Note**: To delete a property, remove the property from the entity, then save the entity.

In the above snippet, for example, deleting the `done` property of the `task` entity, if existing, would be done like this:

```
with client.transaction():
    key = client.key('Task', 'sample_task')
    task = client.get(key)

    if 'done' in task:
        del task['done']
        client.put(task)
```

Comment: How do I remove a property from an entity? or have to use the cloud datastore console?

Comment: @daiyue   See **Note:** in the quote. Maybe something like `unset(task['done'])` (but I'm not 100% certain, I'm not a PHP user)